# How do I make Autofill for excel work properly?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

**Update**: I have tried using other *Excel.XlAutoFillType*, sadly it did not work.

The types are ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlautofilltype?view=excel-pia))

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm new to VSTO and now writing an VSTO add-in for Excel(2013 or higher version). The Autofill method is *Range.AutoFill(Range, XlAutoFillType)* from *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel* (See [Documentation from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofill?view=excel-pia)).

I have a date (like 25.02.2020) and want the excel to autofill the rest of the column with the dates after it (ex. A1:25.02.2020; A2:26.02.2020; A3:27.02.2020; ... A6:01.03.2020; ...).

As I tried **manually** to do it in excel, it **worked**, as long as I selected two or more cells as examples.

*Image see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHPim.png (As StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post photos)*

However, when I tried to use the *autofill* method, it failed and only added the years. (B2 was provided as an example for excel)

*image see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhEQz.png*

**Here is my code:**

```
// Datetime dates[] = new dates[3] {dt1, dt2, dt3}
// Int[] dateLength = new Int[3] {0, (int)Math.Ceiling(dates[1].Subtract(dates[0]).TotalDays), ((int)Math.Ceiling(dates[2].Subtract(dates[1]).TotalDays) + (int)Math.Ceiling(dates[1].Subtract(dates[0]).TotalDays))}

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dates.Length; i++, j++)
    {
    Excel.Worksheet activeWst = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
    Excel.Range tRange = activeWst.Range[activeWst.Cells[dateLength[i] + 2 + j, 2], activeWst.Cells[dateLength[i] + 2 + j, 2]];
    tRange.Value = dates[i].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    if (i < dates.Length - 1) {
        tRange.AutoFill(activeWst.Range[activeWst.Cells[dateLength[i] + 2 + j, 2], activeWst.Cells[dateLength[i + 1] + j + 1, 2]]);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this article carefully, looking at the necessary arguments. You are missing the argument behind . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.autofill?view=vsto-2017

Comment: As I have mentioned, It is not necessary, bacause it will automaticlly be set to xlFillDefault. Also, I dont know which to take since I cant find anything about short form date.

Comment: `namedRange1.AutoFill(this.Range[...],
        Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDays); ` You have tried it?

Comment: your code: `tRange.AutoFill(activeWst.Range[activeWst.Cells[..], activeWst.Cells[... ]],   ???   );` I do not see your final argument

Comment: public object AutoFill (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Destination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFillType Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault); so in my code it would be XlFillDefault

Comment: I will try to use xlFillDays later

Comment: You are wrong, if you do not add arguments then xlFillDefault will be selected as the default, this is the basic thing in vba and .net

Comment: yes, and if it is seleted, then i dont actually miss the argument. There is nothing different if I write the default down.

Comment: so now is the time to choose the argument you need!

Comment: Maybe I should change my question to "which type should man choose" since I did not find anything about short-form-time. BTW, xlFillDays is for weekdays(that I unterstand).. It means: Mon, Tue... Anyway I will try all of them later, and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. As the date value in every cell is stored as *String*, the *Autofill* won't work.

```
tRange.Value = dates[i].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");  //The problem
```

The only thing is to write the dates in the cells directly and change the entire column's number format to what you like.

```
//Fixed code    
tRange.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
tRange.Value = dates[i].Date;
```

And BTW, it works with the default XlAutoFillType(*Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault*).

```
tRange.AutoFill(activeWst.Range[activeWst.Cells[dateLength[i] + 2 + j, 2], activeWst.Cells[dateLength[i + 1] + j + 1, 2]], Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault);
```

I appreciate everyone's help. Thank you a lot.